# How to change the text of a button based on changes to a textformfield

Tags: flutter

```
TextEditingController _popUpDeleteSoldText = new TextEditingController(text: "Delete");
return showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) {
      return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(_popUpDeleteSoldText.text + " " + doc['name'] + "?"),
        content: Container(
          height: 145,
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0),
                child: Align(alignment: Alignment.centerLeft, child: Text('Did you sold the property?', style: TextStyle(color: myColors.blue),)),
              ),
              MyTextFormField(
                soldController,
                'For how much?',
                false,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                digitsOnly: true,
                onChanged: (text) {
                  if (soldController.text != "0.00") {
                    print('text field: $text');
                    setState(() {
                      _popUpDeleteSoldText = new TextEditingController(text: "Sell");
                    });
                  } else {
                    setState(() {
                      _popUpDeleteSoldText = new TextEditingController(text: "Delete");
                    });
                  }
                },
              ),
```

as you can see I'm changing the _popUpDeleteSoldText controller based on the textformfield being changed (mytextformfield is just my own field based on the original, to standardized the design across the app).
That controller is what I use on the popup button to say "sell" or "delete" as I want to change the button text according to the value on the field
I know that the onchanged is triggered as I tested with a print, however, the button always says "delete" (initial initialization) and doesn't update to the "sell"

Answer (score 0):

```
String _btnName = "";

...

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context){

  ...

  TextFormField(

    ...
    autovalidate: true,
    validator: (String txt){
      if (txt.trim().toString()==true){
        setState((){
          _btnName = txt;
        });
      } else {
        setState((){
           _btnName = txt;
        });
      }
    }

    ...

  FlatButton(
    onPressed: _btnName,
    child: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution where, instad of keeping the button text as the state, I keep the property value. I also added a TextInputFormatter in order to accept only positive number.

[image]

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MyWidget(),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int propertyValue = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('Did you sell the property???'),
          IntrinsicWidth(
            child: TextFormField(
              initialValue: propertyValue.toString(),
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                FilteringTextInputFormatter.digitsOnly,
                PositiveNumberFormatter(),
              ],
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              onChanged: (value) =>
                  setState(() => propertyValue = int.parse(value)),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 16.0),
          propertyValue > 0
              ? ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.attach_money),
                  label: Text('Sell'),
                  onPressed: () => print('SELL'),
                )
              : ElevatedButton.icon(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
                  label: Text('Delete'),
                  onPressed: () => print('DELETE'),
                ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class PositiveNumberFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: max(0, double.tryParse(newValue.text) ?? 0).toString(),
      selection: newValue.text.length == 0
          ? TextSelection.collapsed(offset: 1)
          : newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey! First of all thank you for the extensive response, however, it's not working.
all of this is in a showdialog(alertfdialog())
could that be the issue? (even though the absolute parent is build)